# how to solve run time error of [NSURL fileURLWithPath:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class?

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner in IPhone Developing. I want play sound. so, that's why I have apply this code

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSError* err;
    path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Animalfile" ofType:@"plist"];
    dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *animalaudio=[dict valueForKey:@"audio"];
    NSString *audiolist=[animalaudio objectAtIndex:currentsound];
    AVAudioPlayer *audio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    fileURLWithPath:audiolist error:&err]];
    audio.delegate=self;
    [audio play];

}
```

and I have got the run time error of

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x182121c
2012-07-14 14:51:21.711 plistdemo[1236:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:error:]:     
unrecognized selector sent to class 0x182121c'
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

so, give any suggestion and source code which apply in my code

Answer (score 1):

current [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for NSURL doesn't list any such method like 'fileURLWithPath:error:'... seems like its either deprecated or incorrect.

instead try using something like:

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioList]
```

hope it helps...